# Qt: glClear does not work with overpainting on OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qpainter

## Problem

When `QPainter` is created after `glClear` the latter has no effect.

## Description

I use Qt 5.7.1. I get same results with gcc on Linux and vc++ on Windows.

I have the following in a widget derived from `QGLWidget`:

```
void CanvasWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(m_backgroundColor);
}
```

V1:

```
void CanvasWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Produces:

[image]

V2:

```
void CanvasWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Produces:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Which can be done with a hack:

```
void CanvasWidget::paintGL()
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    qglClearColor(m_backgroundColor);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

## Question

What is going on? Why can't `glClean` and `QPainter` work together? Why can't I get it with V1?

## Minimal Reproducible Example

> **main.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainwindow;
    mainwindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

> **MainWindow.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CanvasWidget.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <memory>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    MainWindow(const MainWindow &) = delete;
    MainWindow & operator= (const MainWindow &) = delete;
    virtual ~MainWindow() = default;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<CanvasWidget> m_canvasWidget;
};
```

> **MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , m_canvasWidget(new CanvasWidget(parent))
{
    setCentralWidget(m_canvasWidget.get());
}
```

> **CanvasWidget.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QGLWidget>

class CanvasWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CanvasWidget(QWidget* parent = 0, const QGLWidget* shareWidget = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0);
private:
    virtual void initializeGL() override;
    virtual void paintGL() override;
private:
    QColor m_backgroundColor;
};
```

> **CanvasWidget.cpp**

```
#include "CanvasWidget.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QWheelEvent>

CanvasWidget::CanvasWidget(
    QWidget* parent /*= 0*/,
    const QGLWidget* shareWidget /*= 0*/,
    Qt::WindowFlags f /*= 0 */)
    : QGLWidget(parent, shareWidget, f)
    , m_backgroundColor(0, 93, 196)
{}

void CanvasWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(m_backgroundColor);
}

void CanvasWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting your `CanvasWidget's` [autoFillBackground](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property to `false`.

Comment: @G.M. oh, this could be it. I will test it soon.

Comment: @G.M. you've got an eagle eye: this was it. Could you make an answer from your comment? I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `setAutoFillBackground(false)` in `CanvasWidget` constructor solves the problem.

All the credit goes to @G.M.

Comment: Just adding to this, you can also use the `setAutoFillBackground` functionality to your advantage by setting the desired background color in Qt. One way to do this is with `setPalette()` (e.g. get the palette first via `palette()`, modify background, set it back).

Answer (score 0):

In [Qt tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/opengl-overpainting.html) about overpainting OpenGL with QPainter it is stated:

> When overpainting 2D content onto 3D content, we need to use a
>   QPainter and make OpenGL calls to achieve the desired effect. Since
>   QPainter itself uses OpenGL calls when used on a QGLWidget subclass,
>   we need to preserve the state of various OpenGL stacks when we perform
>   our own calls

So, looking at your code in V1 I suppose that QPainter sets its own clear color state, and if you don't set your glClearColor explicitly, you will get what QPainter object has set.
And I would also suggest you to use a tool like [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/builds) or [gDebugger](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/gDEBugger/) to trace GL commands of your app to see exactly what happens under the hood.